Was Paul's Washing in Acts 9:18 a Ritual Purification Rather Than a Christian Baptism?
In Acts 9:18, following his encounter with Jesus on the road to Damascus, it is recorded that Saul (Paul) regained his sight, εβαπτίσθη (was baptized), and then took food to regain his strength. The Greek text states:

"και ευθεως απεπεσαν απο των οφθαλμων αυτου ωσει λεπιδες και ανεβλεψεν και αναστας εβαπτισθη και λαβων τροφην ενισχυθη."

This sequence of events — particularly the washing followed by eating — reminds me of Luke 11:38, where a Pharisee is surprised that Jesus does not perform a ritual washing before dinner. The relevant Greek text from Luke 11:38 says:

"και ιδων ο Φαρισαιος εθαυμασεν οτι ου πρωτον εβαπτισθη προ του αριστου."

Given Paul's background as a Pharisee and his deep roots in Jewish traditions, could this "εβαπτίσθη" be more accurately interpreted as a ritual washing in line with Jewish customs, rather than a Christian baptism symbolizing rebirth and conversion?
This interpretation would see Paul's act not as a definitive break with his past, but rather as a continuity of his Jewish faith, possibly representing a purification in preparation for his new mission, rather than an initiation into Christian faith.
What are the implications of viewing Paul's washing in this light, especially in terms of understanding early Christian practices and their connection to Jewish traditions? Are there other textual or historical contexts that support or refute this interpretation?

The Greek verb βαπτίζω (baptizó) occurs 81 times in the NT and can be classified as follows:

Ceremonial/ritual submersion in water for the purpose of renewing or establishing a relationship with God, eg, Matt 3:6, 3:11a, 13, 14, 16, 28:19, Mark 1:5, 8a, 16:16, Acts 2:41, 8:12, 36, 38, 9:18, 10:47, 16:15, 33, 18:8, 22:16, Rom 6:3, 1 Cor 1:14-17, etc.  This is by far the most common meaning in the NT and the only meaning in the book of Acts.

to be baptized by the Holy Spirit, Matt 3:11b, Mark 1:8b, Luke 3:16b, John 1:33, Acts 1:5b, 11:16b, 1 Cor 12:13.

Metaphorically meaning to have an extraordinary spiritual experience or ordeal, Matt 20:22, Mark 10:28, 39, Luke 12:50.

Ceremonial washing of hands, Mark 7:4, Luke 11:38.


Thus, the evidence appears to point toward the baptism in Acts 9:18 being the usual bodily baptism, not just the washing of the hands; especially in view of the fact that Acts 9:18 is essentially the conversion of Paul which would involve much more than simply washing his hands.

+1 Also the washing of one's hands was routine among the Pharisees. There would be no reason to mention it, any more than to mention saying the blessing over bread. https://www.myjewishlearning.com/article/hand-washing/

There might be a logical error in equating the frequency of the word "βαπτίζω" in later contexts with its specific meaning in Acts 9:18. Frequency does not necessarily dictate meaning, particularly in unique contexts where the term might carry its original or more symbolic implications of purification and transformation. This broader perspective is essential to accurately interpreting the text.

@DanFefferman thanks for adding this perspective. I think it could be the opposite so that it understrikes the fact that Paul is still following the oral law.

@DanFefferman - excellent point and well stated.  Many thanks.

@Dottard Interesting, I thought it was simply the Greek word for being immersed in something, but I've never looked up the usages, it is always used for religious actions? I would have thought there would be non-religious uses of the word as well.

@Nacht - in the secular Greek world that is true (meaning to dye a cloth by "baptizing it") but in the NT it acquired a technical meaning as outlined above.

Ananias, being a Jew, would have certainly been water baptized himself at some point in preparation for Israel's "times of refreshing" (Acts 3:19).  Paul would not yet have been made aware from Christ ascended (nor would Ananias have had any idea) that water baptism would soon not be a requirement.
Although it is not explicitly stated that Ananias performed a water baptism on Paul, I believe it is safe to say that this is what is implied, rather than for the purpose of Paul preparing to eat.
Consider that Peter water baptized Cornelius after "the Holy Ghost fell on him" (Acts 10:44), which strengthens the idea that this is the type of baptism being referenced.
Paul later admits that he also, not yet knowing differently, baptized a few new believers, but states that unlike Peter's commission, Christ's purpose in sending Paul was not about baptizing, but rather to preach his gospel (1 Corinthians 1:16-18).
An important part of Paul's gospel includes the completeness a believer has been gifted upon having placed their faith in Christ (Colossians 2:9-13).  Peter also later realizes and writes of salvation by Christ's baptism of resurrection, rather than by that of "the putting away of the filth of the flesh" (with water):
1 Peter 3:21

The like figure whereunto even baptism doth also now save us (not the putting away of the filth of the flesh, but the answer of a good conscience toward God,) by the resurrection of Jesus Christ:

To conclude, prior to Christ's death, burial, resurrection and ascension into glory, the emphasis of water baptism was paramount.  Considering that the book of Acts is transitionary from what was to what now is, the requirement of any baptism performed on or by a believer (regardless of which type is being referenced in Acts 9:18) was realised to be unnecessary, as the one baptism that now matters is performed by the Spirit, into the body of Christ, and without the need of water.
1 Corinthians 12:13

For by one Spirit are we all baptized into one body, whether we be Jews or Gentiles, whether we be bond or free; and have been all made to drink into one Spirit.

Ephesians 4:5

One Lord, one faith, one baptism,


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
